# Why the list variable named nodes in the class is taking the output of the previous instance of the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, class-instance-variables

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.data = value
        self.next = None
        
class SinglyLinkedList:
    nodes = []
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def insertHead(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        
        if(self.head is None):
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
            return
        
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        
    def insertTail(self, value):
        node = Node(value)
        
        if(self.tail is None):
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
            return
        
        self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node
    
    def displayNodes(self):
        temp = self.head
        
        while (temp is not None):
            self.nodes.append(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next
            
        return self.nodes    
        
### Object 1
obj1 = SinglyLinkedList()
obj1.insertHead(8)
obj1.insertHead(7)
obj1.insertHead(5)
obj1.insertTail(30)
print(obj1.displayNodes())

### Object 2
obj2 = SinglyLinkedList()
obj2.insertHead(20)
obj2.insertHead(10)
print(obj2.displayNodes())

### Object 3
obj3 = SinglyLinkedList()
obj3.insertHead(50)
obj3.insertHead(22)
obj3.insertHead(19)
print(obj3.displayNodes())
print(obj3.nodes)

### Object 4
obj4 = SinglyLinkedList()
obj4.insertHead(45)
obj4.insertHead(40)
obj4.insertHead(35)
obj4.insertHead(28)
print(obj4.displayNodes())
```

### Output

```
python flatten_LL.py
[5, 7, 8, 30]
[5, 7, 8, 30, 10, 20]
[5, 7, 8, 30, 10, 20, 19, 22, 50]
[5, 7, 8, 30, 10, 20, 19, 22, 50]
[5, 7, 8, 30, 10, 20, 19, 22, 50, 28, 35, 40, 45]
```

> This the code of a singly linked list. I have created four instances and i am storing the linked list value in the list variable named "nodes". For each instance i am returning that list variable "nodes".
> As you can see the output, from the second instance, display of the nodes the output of the previous instance is still staying as it is. I want to know why this is happenning, as for each instance the storage is allocated to that instance separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `nodes` is (essentially) [a static variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python).

You probably meant to write this:

```
class SinglyLinkedList:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
```